# Hide a questiomark in url?

Tags: javascript, php, url, replace

I had url which looks like http://localhost/dashboard/index.php?id=1 so that i would pass the value in url as per use and switch the dashboard accordingly. All i wanted is url should be visible like http://localhost/dashboard/index.php or even http://localhost/dashboard/index.php/1. I want to hide or replace a url string(for visibility) and not to redirect which i tried using htaccess. can we do that using JavaScript??

Comment: you'd need some server side magic, changing the `dicument.location.search` property reloads the page

Comment: You can achieve using htaccess

Answer (score 0):

You can push state in browser history javascript. This will change your current page's url without redirecting to new url. Try below code in page load event.

```
history.pushState("", "", "1");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use AJAX to get your data from the php file and display the content on your browser.
This will avoid redirection and also the url will remain clean.

Haven't tried it but here's what you can do:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p><span id="dashboardView"></span></p> 
<span class="btn" val="1" onclick="showDashboard(this)">Dashboard 1</span>

<script>
function showDashboard(elem) {
  var xhttp;
  var val = elem.getAttribute("val");

  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("dashboardView").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "dashboard/index.php?id="+val, true);
  xhttp.send();   
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var urlStr = 'http://localhost/dashboard/index.php?id=1';
var nextURL = urlStr.replace("?", "");
alert(nextURL);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.